# Python FreeCad ActiveDocument with variable

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I'm quite new to Python so the answer to my question might be simple or impossible.

In below shown example I would like to substitute the object name "**myBox**" with a variable **boxName**.

*boxName = "myBox"
FreeCAD.ActiveDocument.addObject("Part::Box", boxName)**

This works:

*FreeCAD.ActiveDocument.**myBox**.Length = 150*

This doesn't:

*FreeCAD.ActiveDocument. + **boxName** + .Length = 150*

I get a syntax error:

'*App.Document' object has no attribute 'boxName' or when I try other variations I get this error:
(1)<class 'SyntaxError'>: ('invalid syntax', ('###/AppData/Roaming/FreeCAD/Macro/nyMacro.FCMacro', 5, 24, 'FreeCAD.ActiveDocument.+(boxName)+.Length = 150\n'))*

If it's possible to substitute with a variable, I will be gratefull if someone will show me the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use meta programming. Do a little study about this concept. It's interesting. In Python you can execute dynamic code by eval function:

eval('FreeCAD.ActiveDocument. + boxName + .Length = 150')

Do seaech about eval and exec function if I'm not wrong.